# Python Program Not Posting/Updating Events When Database Has New Values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a Python program that is designed to post and update events to an API based on data from a database. The program works fine initially and successfully posts and updates events. However, when there is no data in the database for a period of time, the program goes to sleep, and when new data is added to the database, the program does not resume posting/updating events or show any errors.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import time
from typing import Tuple,List, Dict, Union
from datetime import timedelta
from Utility.API.main_api import Main_API1
from Utility.utilities import CUSTOM_DT
from Utility.DB_Manager import Custom_DB
from Utility.heat_map import Generate_HeatMap

event_created_images="assets/event_created_images/"

class Posting_Event:
    def __init__(self):
        # Initalize the DataBase
        self.ready_post_col = Custom_DB(db_name="mydatabase",col_name="ready_post_api")
        self.comp_post_api = Custom_DB(db_name="mydatabase",col_name="event_posted")
        self.update_event = Custom_DB(db_name="mydatabase",col_name="update_events")
        self.duration_DB = Custom_DB(db_name="mydatabase", col_name="update_duration")

        # Create the Instance of Api Class
        self.api = Main_API1()

        # Create the Instance of heatmap
        self.heat_map = Generate_HeatMap()

        self.record_count:int =0
    def check_and_update(self):
        # Define the check for update Function

        if data := self.update_event.find_one_data():
             if (r := self.comp_post_api.find_one_data(query={"update_unique_id":data.get("_id")})):
                 response = self.api.update_events(update_unique_id=data.get("_id"), data={
                     "gender": data.get('gender'),
                     "age": data.get("age")})
                 if response in [200,204]:
                     print("event update :",self.update_event.delete_one(query={"_id":data.get("_id")}))
                 else:
                     print(response)
        #    Update the duration
        if data := self.duration_DB.find_one_data():
            if (r := self.comp_post_api.find_one_data(query={"update_unique_id": data.get("_id")})):
                if response := self.api.update_events(update_unique_id=data.get("_id"), data={
                    "spending_time": data.get("spending_time")}) in [200, 204]:
                    print("Update the spending time in this current event ", data.get("_id"))
                    self.duration_DB.delete_one(query={"_id": data.get("_id")})

    def post_api(self):
        next_one_hour = CUSTOM_DT.g_c_ist_dt(Type="obj",zone="UTC")+timedelta(minutes=30)
        print("Generate heat map at : ",next_one_hour)
        while True:
            # Call the check to update event
            self.check_and_update()
            # Trigger the heat map generator
            if CUSTOM_DT.g_c_ist_dt(Type="obj",zone="UTC") > next_one_hour:
                next_one_hour = CUSTOM_DT.g_c_ist_dt(Type="obj", zone="UTC") + timedelta(minutes=30)
                pass

            # Post event to api
            if posted_data := self.ready_post_col.find_one_data():
                if os.path.exists(f"{event_created_images}{posted_data['image']}"):
                    print("Start to upload the event details")
                    if response := self.api.file_upload_images(filepath=f"{event_created_images}{posted_data['image']}") in [200,204]:
                        print(f"image upload sucessfully {posted_data['image']}")
                        os.remove(f"{event_created_images}{posted_data['image']}")
                    else:
                        continue
                    id = posted_data["_id"]

                    posted_data.pop("_id")
                    if response := self.api.post_events(data=posted_data) in [200,204]:
                        print(f'event posted successfully')
                        self.ready_post_col.delete_one(query={'_id': id})
                        self.record_count +=1
                    else:
                        continue

                    # add the data to complete data base
                    self.comp_post_api.add_one(data=posted_data)
                    print(f"{self.record_count}  number of record are posted in Api")
                else:
                    # delete the posted record
                    self.ready_post_col.delete_one(query={"_id":posted_data['_id']})
                    self.update_event.delete_one(query={"_id":posted_data['_id']})
                    print("Record delete on the posting part : ",posted_data["_id"],"No image")
            else:
                time.sleep(1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        post=Posting_Event()
        post.post_api()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exiting ..")
```

The program structure is as follows:

1. It checks for updates in the database and updates events if necessary.
2. It generates a heatmap at specific intervals.
3. It posts events to the API if there is data in the database.

The issue I'm facing is that when there is a gap in new data being added to the database, the program doesn't seem to resume posting/updating events even when new data becomes available. I suspect there may be an issue with how I handle the sleep and data checking.

I would like to know what could be causing this issue and how I can fix it so that the program properly resumes posting/updating events when new data is added to the database.